# Compositional layout with centred items and centred paging

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Need some help here. I'm building an interesting layout, where cells are centered depending on their count. Probably, best thing to explain is to illustrate a little demo.
Here it is:

[image]

On the left we have a behaviour of how layout acts depending on items in datasource. On the right - illustration of seven cells in collection view.

I have some thoughts about triple grouping, but probably you can help me with more simple solution using compositional layout.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, I figured out how to make such kind of layout.

Firstly, we need to deal with groups. Here is basic illustration what we need to do:

[image]

Probably, at this point you'll have questions, that nice. I can't answer all of them, but here is algorithm:

1. We need to separate all our items into chunks by 2. So each group must have max 2 items. And max groups in section must be equal to 2
2. If item if group is less than 2, we apply left inset to group contentInsets.
3. Section can have orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered if needed.

Probably in code it can be achieved in this way:

```
private func makeLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { [weak self] _, _ -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
            guard let self = self else { return nil }
            var nestedGroupHeight: CGFloat = 250

            if numberOfItems > 2 {
                nestedGroupHeight = 500
            }

            let chunkSize = 4 
            let chunks = stride(from: 0, to: numberOfItems, by: chunkSize).map {
                Array($0..<min($0 + chunkSize, numberOfItems)).count
            }

            var allGroups: [NSCollectionLayoutGroup] = []

            for chunk in chunks {

                var group: [NSCollectionLayoutGroup] = []

                // This code probably can be reduced to 2-3 lines.
                // For now - it's for better understanding on what's going on here

                if chunk == 4 { // 4 speakers, two groups of 2
                    group.append(self.createGroup(2))
                    group.append(self.createGroup(2))
                } else if chunk == 3 { // 3 items, one group of 2 and one group of 1
                    group.append(self.getTopSpeakersGroup(2))
                    group.append(self.getTopSpeakersGroup(1))
                } else if chunk == 2 { // 2 items, one group of 2
                    group.append(self.getTopSpeakersGroup(2))
                } else if chunk == 1 { // 1 items, one group of 1
                    group.append(self.getTopSpeakersGroup(1))
                }

                let mainGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
                    layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                        widthDimension: .absolute(UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 45),
                        heightDimension: .estimated(nestedGroupHeight)),
                    subitems: group
                )

                group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(10)

                allGroups.append(group)
            }

            let nestedGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
                layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .absolute(UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 45),
                heightDimension: .estimated(nestedGroupHeight)),
                subitems: allGroups)

            nestedGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(15)

            let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: nestedGroup)
            layoutSection.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered

            return layoutSection

        }

    }

    private func createGroup(_ count: Int) -> NSCollectionLayoutGroup {
        let itemWidth = BoardTopMemberCell.width
        let groupHeight: CGFloat = 250
        let groupWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 45

        let trailingItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
            layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .absolute(itemWidth),
                heightDimension: .estimated(groupHeight)
            )
        )

        var leftInset: CGFloat = groupWidth / 2 - 15/2 - itemWidth

        if count < 2 {
            leftInset = groupWidth / 2 - itemWidth / 2
        }

        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(groupWidth),
                                               heightDimension: .estimated(groupHeight))

        let trailingGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
            layoutSize: groupSize,
            subitems: [trailingItem]
        )
        trailingGroup.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: leftInset, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
        trailingGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(15)

        return trailingGroup
    }
```